# Why is $12\cdot 12=144$ but $8 \cdot 16=128$? (I was asked by a co-worker)

Tags: arithmetic

Why is $12\cdot 12=144$ but $8 \cdot 16=128$? a friend thinks it should be the same because $12+12=24$ and $8+16=24$. He said it is only $4$ that is moved to the other side. Please give some sort of reason so I can inform him. thanks

Comment: Take a piece of graph paper. Outline a rectangle $12$ squares wide and $12$ tall, and one rectangle $16$ by $8$. Have him count the number of squares in each of them.

Comment: $2+2=3+1$, therefore $4=2*2=3*1=3$.

Comment: I think your friend is trolling you...

Comment: What does your friend think happens when "it is only 12 that is moved to the other side" and the product becomes $0\cdot 24$?

Comment: Tell your friend you will give him $8 \cdot 16$ dollars *and* the answer to his question if he gives you $12 \cdot 12$ dollars.

Comment: Respond "Well, that's silly. There's absolutely no reason to believe that just because you move part of a number from one piece of a mathematical expression to another you'll get the same result. I mean, take $2^4$. If I take $2$ away from the exponent and add it to the base, I'll have $4^2$, and ... OH MY GOD!"

Comment: Indeed it is no coincidence that the difference is $4^2=16$.

Answer (score 3):

**Intuitive answer:** Let's look at a simple case of $2\times2$ and $1\times3$. Those two definitely don't equal, in fact, the second will always be smaller than the first.

I highly recommend what Arthur suggested in the comments - in fact, you may even visualise why this is true by taking the bottom $4$ rows as collumns and cutting away the parts that "sticks out" - a $4\times4$ square (I would draw this, but my MathJax skills are sadly not up to par here.

**Edit:** Well I tried anyway. Take $4\times 4$ and $2\times 6$
 \begin{matrix}
        \cdot & \cdot & \cdot & \cdot \\
        \cdot & \cdot & \cdot & \cdot \\
        \color{red}{\cdot} & \color{red}{\cdot} &\color{red}{\cdot} &\color{red}{\cdot} \\
        \color{red}{\cdot} & \color{red}{\cdot}&\color{red}{\cdot} & \color{red}{\cdot} \\
        \end{matrix}

\begin{matrix}
        \cdot & \cdot & \cdot & \cdot & \color{red}{\cdot} & \color{red}{\cdot} \\
        \cdot & \cdot & \cdot & \cdot & \color{red}{\cdot}&\color{red}{\cdot} \\
         &  &  &  & \color{fuchsia}{\cdot} & \color{fuchsia}{\cdot} \\
         & &  & & \color{fuchsia}{\cdot} & \color{fuchsia}{\cdot}\\
        \end{matrix}

**Mathematical answer**: For $b >0$ $$ (a-b)(a+b)=a^2 - b^2 < a ^2$$

Comment: Just to fill in the mathematical answer, this is what he means:
$$8 \cdot 16 = (12 - 4)(12 + 4) = 12^2 - 4^2 < 12^2 = 144$$

Comment: Dammit, thanks for that. I've always been bad at inequalities ever since high school :>

Comment: The first time I encountered inequality signs, in elementary school, I was told it symbolized the mascot of our textbook (a crow) gaping towards the biggest basket of apples, the greedy bastard. Has helped me since, though.

Answer (score 2):

Suppose you have two numbers $x,y$ whose sum is $24$ and whose product is $144$. That is,

$$x+y=24,\\
x\,y=144.$$

Just knowing the sum and product, we can figure out what $x$ and $y$ must be. Subtracting $x$ from both sides in the first equation isolates $y$: $~~~~y=24-x.$ Substituting this expression for $y$ into the second equation yields:

$$x\,(24-x)=144\\
\Leftrightarrow 24x-x^2=144\\
\Leftrightarrow 0=x^2-24x+144=(x-12)^2\\
\Leftrightarrow x=12.$$

From $y=24-x$, we find $y=24-12=12.$

In general, a pair of numbers is determined by their sum and product. If you believed your friend who thinks that a pair's sum determines its product, then you end up with the following contradiction: $$\text{Suppose two different pairs of numbers have the same sum.}\\
\text{If they have the same sum, they also have the same product.}\\
\text{But if two pairs of numbers have both the same sum and product, the pairs are actually identical.}\\
\text{Since two things cannot be both different and the same, contradiction.}\\
$$

Answer (score 0):

> *because $12+12=24$ and $8+16=24$.*

Tell your friend that $0+24$ is also $24$... :-)

---

> *He said it is **only** $4$ that is moved to the other side.*

Then tell him that the difference between $128$ and $144$ is also “only” $4^2=16$... :-)